# XSLT 2.0: Transforming an element including all ancestors without using a foreach

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I'm currently trying to transform an XML file to several output XML files by taking certain element of it and traversing up the ancestors of the chosen elements.

For example:

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <level_a> 
    <level_b> 
      <level_c> 
        <level_d> 
          <level_e/> 
        </level_d> 
      </level_c> 
    </level_b> 
    <level_b> 
      <level_c> 
        <level_d> 
          <level_e/> 
        </level_d> 
      </level_c> 
    </level_b> 
    <level_b> 
      <level_c> 
        <level_d> 
          <level_e/> 
          <level_e/> 
          <level_e/> 
        </level_d> 
      </level_c> 
    </level_b> 
    <level_b> 
      <level_c> 
        <level_d> 
          <level_d> 
            <level_e/> 
          </level_d> 
        </level_d> 
      </level_c> 
    </level_b>
  </level_a>
</root>
```

Output XML files:

1:

```
 <output>
        <output level="b"> 
          <output level="c"> 
            <output level="d"> 
              <output level="e"/> 
            </output> 
          </output> 
        </output> 
 </output>
```

2:

```
 <output>
        <output level="b"> 
          <output level="c"> 
            <output level="d"> 
              <output level="e"/> 
            </output> 
          </output> 
        </output> 
 </output>
```

3:

```
 <output>
        <output level="b"> 
          <output level="c"> 
            <output level="d"> 
              <output level="e"/>
              <output level="e"/> 
              <output level="e"/>  
            </output> 
          </output> 
        </output> 
 </output>
```

4:

```
 <output>
      <output level="b"> 
        <output level="c"> 
          <output level="d"> 
            <output level="d"> 
              <output level="e"/> 
            </output> 
          </output> 
        </output> 
      </output>
 </output>
```

I know I can do something in the line of generating a sequence with following XPath:

(//level_d[not(level_d)])[last()]/ancestor::*[self::level_c|self::level_b]

and then iterate it with a foreach and I will get my results in the document order.

But what I'm really interested in, is how to achieve the same without resorting to the use of a foreach, any solutions I can think of would return all elements reversed...

Any hint are greatly appreciated

Best Regards
Vlax

Comment: Couldn't you just match `/*/*` and create your result document from there?

Comment: You may need to elaborate the question (or ask another); it's not at all clear from this question why Daniel Haley's approach doesn't solve your problem.  You get points for simplifying away from extraneous details in posing the question, but remember Einstein's advice:  as simple as possible, but no simpler!

Comment: Now I've changed the example that was really over simplified, the actual version should reflect my real life xml source.
Actually the xml doesn't have to have 2 elements at after the root element it can have any number or just one. The only certainty I have is that there are level_d elements and those must be extracted to output xml files with all the ancestors tree up to a certain element (e.g. element_a in my example xml).

Comment: @Vlax - How do you determine what "element_a" is? Is it the first element that contains more than one child element?

Comment: @DanielHaley actually element_a is a known element whose name is element_a for instance

Comment: @Vlax - If "element_a" is known, you can change the `match="/*/*"` to `match="level_a/*"` in my answer and it creates the 4 desired output files with the updated XML input you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a variable solution, you can adjust the values here if level_a or level_d ever changes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="//level_d[not(ancestor::level_d)]">
            <xsl:result-document href="{concat('file_', count(preceding::*[self::level_d])+1,'.xml')}">
                <output>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor-or-self::node()[parent::level_a]" mode="output"></xsl:apply-templates>
                </output>
            </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="output">
        <output level="{substring-after(local-name(),'level_')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="output"/>
        </output>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It has the same results as expected.

Comment: Thanks! This exactly what I was looking for. Not always wrong :)

Comment: In fact you can write "level_d[not(ancestor::level_d)]" instead of "//level_d[not(ancestor::level_d)]"

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why you would go bottom up instead of top down. I would match `/*/*` and create the result document there.

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <level_a> 
        <level_b> 
            <level_c> 
                <level_d> 
                    <level_e/> 
                </level_d> 
            </level_c> 
        </level_b> 
    </level_a>
    <level_b> 
        <level_c> 
            <level_d> 
                <level_d> 
                    <level_e/> 
                </level_d> 
            </level_d> 
        </level_c> 
    </level_b>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template name="output">
        <output level="{substring-after(name(),'level_')}">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </output>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/*" priority="1">
        <xsl:result-document href="{generate-id()}.xml">
            <output>
                <xsl:call-template name="output"/>              
            </output>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(),'level_')]">
        <xsl:call-template name="output"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**File 1** (name will be different because of `generate-id()`)

```
<output>
   <output level="a">
      <output level="b">
         <output level="c">
            <output level="d">
               <output level="e"/>
            </output>
         </output>
      </output>
   </output>
</output>
```

**File 2** (name will be different because of `generate-id()`)

```
<output>
   <output level="b">
      <output level="c">
         <output level="d">
            <output level="d">
               <output level="e"/>
            </output>
         </output>
      </output>
   </output>
</output>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I may have oversimplified my example.
Actually I need to start at "level_d" because my actual xml is much more complex.
If you wish I can try to reproduce a more real life example.
But basically I need to go use either ancestor::* or parent::* recursively...

Comment: @Vlax - Could you check to see if there is a descendant "level_d" (`match="/*/*[descendant::level_d]"`)? You could stop processing at "level_d" by adding a template to match it specifically. An updated example might help me understand why you would want to go backwards up the tree.

Comment: Sorry for my first version of the xml now it should reflect better the actual xml. If you look in the last version you will see that the first level_b element has many level_d elements down in his the tree. So my idea was to locate all level_d elements extract the ancestors and the get the children. Each level_d on a separate file. From the nested level_d I only need to care about the last in the tree, the others nested level_d upwards the tree doesn't need a separate file and are regarded only as ancestors.

Comment: @Vlax - If "element_a" is known, you can change the `match="/*/*"` to `match="level_a/*"` in my answer and it creates the 4 desired output files with the updated XML input you provided.